# Perl replace produces empty file from script, not from bash

Tags: linux, bash, perl, replace

I'm getting pretty frustrated with this problem at the moment. I can't see what I'm doing wrong. I have this problem with google chrome that it gives a notice of not being shut down properly. I want to get rid of this. Also I have some older replaces that have to do with full screen size. In bash, all the lines produce the expected result; however, in a script file, it produces an empty settings file...

These lines are in the file:

```
cat ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Preferences | perl -pe "s/\"work_area_bottom.*/\"work_area_bottom\": $(xrandr | grep \* | cut -d' ' -f4 | cut -d'x' -f2),/" > ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Preferences
cat ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Preferences | perl -pe "s/\"bottom.*/\"bottom\": $(xrandr | grep \* | cut -d' ' -f4 | cut -d'x' -f2),/" > ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Preferences
cat ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Preferences | perl -pe "s/\"work_area_right.*/\"work_area_right\": $(xrandr | grep \* | cut -d' ' -f4 | cut -d'x' -f1),/" > ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Preferences
cat ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Preferences | perl -pe "s/\"right.*/\"right\": $(xrandr | grep \* | cut -d' ' -f4 | cut -d'x' -f1),/" > ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Preferences
cat ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Preferences | perl -pe "s/\"exit_type.*/\"exit_type\": \"Normal\",/" > ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Preferences
cat ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Preferences | perl -pe "s/\"exited_cleanly.*/\"exited_cleanly\": true,/" > ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Preferences
```

I've been googling a lot for this issue; however, I do not get the right search words to get a helpful result.

Problem is solved by using the `perl -p -i -e` option like so:

```
perl -p -i -e "s/\"exit_type.*/\"exit_type\": \"Normal\",/" ~/.config/google_chrome/Default/Preferences
```

The above line is enough to get rid of the Google chrome message of incorrect shutdown

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/135507/linux-how-to-use-a-file-as-input-and-output-at-the-same-time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is almost certainly:

```
 > ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Preferences
```

Because that `>` says 'truncate the file'. And worse - it does this *first* before starting to read it. So you truncate the file before reading it, resulting in a zero length file feeding into a zero length file.

I would suggest you want to do this exclusively in perl, rather than a halfway house. `perl` supports the `-i` option for an "in place edit".

Or just write your script in `perl` to start with. (If give sample input and output, knocking up an example that'll do what you want will be quite straightforward).

Comment: Thanks a lot, for this quick answer! you saved my day. The problem is solved using the -in-line replacement option, i'll update the question when possible!

Answer (score 1):

If you need search and replace some text I suggest use:

```
ack -l --print0 '2011...' ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Preferences | xargs -0 -n 1 sed -i -e 's/2011../2015.../g'
```